# Count Rows on multiple tables for each of multiple ids

Tags: mysql, vba

I wrote an sql query for counting (on three tables) the rows related to an Id:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT `Id` FROM `Tab1` WHERE `Id` = '1') AS ID, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab1` WHERE `Id` = '1') AS RowsTab1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab2` WHERE `Id` = '1') AS RowsTab2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab3` WHERE `Id` = '1') AS RowsTab3
```

But I need this on an array of Ids so that the query result is a table that shows, for each Id, how many rows are there in each of the three tables.

The result should be something like :

```
ID    RowsTab1     RowsTab2     RowsTab3
 1        2            4            2
 2        3            0            8
 5        0            2            4
```

and so on

Is there a way to do it with only one query?

I want to clarify that the query will be performed using Excel - VBA

Thanks in advance

Comment: `(SELECT Id FROM Tab1 WHERE Id = '1') AS ID`  This is always 1 (assuming there is an Id of 1), seems useless.

Comment: I simplified the query using names simplest than the real ones for fields and tables. I need that to have the reference of the count(s)

Comment: Yes, but you're only selecting the Id where Id = 1.  It is a pretty pointless query.   It is almost equivalent to `select 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should solve your problem:

```
SELECT Tab0.id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab1` WHERE `Id` = Tab0.Id) AS RowsTab1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab2` WHERE `Id` = Tab0.Id) AS RowsTab2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab3` WHERE `Id` = Tab0.Id) AS RowsTab3
FROM Tab0 WHERE field1 = 'myvalue'
```

Comment: In place of `Tab1 as source` I tryed to insert the query: `(SELECT id FROM Tab0 WHERE field1 = 'myvalue')  as source`
I also tryed to make a temporary table but I don't know the correct syntax.
So I got only errors. May you suggest me the right syntax?

Comment: thanks, it works. Now I only have to check that the result is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the counts you want by using correlated subqueries.  You then need a source for the `ids`, which you can put into a subquery.  Something like this:

```
select ids.id,
       (select count(*) from tabl where tabl1.id = ids.id) as tab1_cnt,
       (select count(*) from tab2 where tabl2.id = ids.id) as tab2_cnt,
       (select count(*) from tab3 where tabl3.id = ids.id) as tab3_cnt
from (select 1 as id union all select 2 union all select 5) as ids
```

If the ids you care about are already in a table, then you can just use that table.

Comment: The Ids I need are in an array

Comment: @genespos . . . You can use the array to generate the SQL code in the `from` clause.

Comment: I think so but I don't know the way.. any suggest?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to go further back: I get the array with this query: `SELECT id FROM Tab0 WHERE field1 = 'myvalue'`

Comment: So I need to know how to use the result of this query to create "ids.id"